# How to convert a foreach within a foreach to LINQ, if it's possible

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, foreach, linq-to-objects, where-clause

I have a foreach that is within a foreach and I would love to convert it to LINQ. If it was just 1 foreach I could use a Where but I am confused. Here is my code.

Basically I need to find the invoice but it depends on metadata which is 2 levels down. I think the code is self-explanatory.

```
currentMetaData >>> Is created outside of the foreach code 
It's an object, but the code below works.

foreach (var item in this.invoices.Items)
{
  foreach (var metaData in item.MetaDatas)
  {
    if (metaData == currentMetaData)
    {
      name = item.Name;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I would love to shorten it with LINQ. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This would give all the names**

```
 var name = 
             from i in this.invoices
             from m in i.Metadata
             where m == currentMetadata
             select i.Name;
```

**Only First Value** to simulate the `break;` statement in your existing loop.

```
 string name = 
             (from i in this.invoices
             from m in i.Metadata
             where m == currentMetadata
             select i.Name).First();
```

Comment: great stuff .. thanks! .. i suppose its not possible to convert to LAMBDAs because there are 2 Froms?? is that correcT?

Comment: @Martin: No, you can use the lambda form for this, with SelectMany calls.

Comment: Why have you called `ToList` here? That's not going to be doing anything useful - in fact, it removes part of the point of using First (which is to stop evaluating the query as soon as you've reached the first element).

Comment: @Jon, right, I was trying out different forms, and I ignorantly left the ToList() as I was writing different forms inside the parantheses :) thanks for pointing out, I'm editing it.

Comment: Hi Jon, Do you have an example of the selectmany for use with my query? This interests me..